# why the scrolling in not working (why list is not scrolling)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to make one demo in which when user type in text field it show the list.It look like auto complete in when user type in text field it show the filter list .But my issue is my list is not scrolling .I already use **overflow :auto ; or overflow :scroll** .But nothing work for me .could you please tell me how to scroll the list ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGEpMN

```
.listcontainer{
  overflow: auto;
  border :1px solid blue;
  height:150px;

}

<div class="listcontainer" ng-show="station.stationCode">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="station in data.data | filter:station.stationCode:startsWith">{{station.stationName+"-("+station.stationCode+")"}}</li>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working in your codepen

Comment: @Reena you see the scroll bar ..but when you touch up and down it not scrolling the list.first type "A" in text field the move up and down list will not scroll

Comment: See this if it helps http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNrOm

Comment: @Reena can it apply on my example

Comment: Are you using firefox? In chrome it's working fine but not in chrome, as iused chrome i wasn't able to see your problem but now I'm clear to it.

Comment: yes I am using chrome.Actually your example is working fine in chrome.but my example is not working mean it is not scrolling the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75919/discussion-between-user944513-and-reena).

Comment: In    .listcontainer class add  position:relative; and check if it work